# How can I use variable in useState hook in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'd like to declare the same number of useState hooks with the userInputs array's length.
And I want to name them like userInput0, userInput1, userInput2,,,userInputN
But "const [userInput+index.toString(), setUserInput] = useState('')" throws an error.
How can I fix it?

```
'use client';
import { useState } from 'react';
userInputs = ['hoge', '123', 'aaa'];
    userInputs.array.forEach((element, index) => {
    const [userInput+index.toString(), setUserInput] = useState('')
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

I think despite that this is something that you could probably do I wouldn't recommend it because it could lead to unexpected behavior

There are some rules in order to use hooks and you are breaking one of them

**Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions**

https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

I recommend you that you create  component with its own state and with your array render 3 different components with their states

Answer (score 1):

To dynamically declare multiple useState hooks with names like "userInput0", "userInput1", "userInput2", etc., you can't directly concatenate the variable name as a string. However, you can achieve this using an object or an array to store the state values. Here's an example of how you can accomplish it:

```js
 const userInputs = ['hoge', '123', 'aaa'];
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({});

  userInputs.forEach((element, index) => {
    const stateName = 'userInput' + index;
    if (!inputs.hasOwnProperty(stateName)) {
      setInputs((prevInputs) => ({ ...prevInputs, [stateName]: '' }));
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to create variables dynamically like `var0`, `var1`, `var2`, then just use an array.

```
const userInputs = [];
const setUserInputs = [];
userInputs.forEach((element, index) => {
  const [xuserInput, setUserInput] = useState('');
  userInputs.push(xuserInput);
  setUserInputs.push(setUserInput);
});
```